# how can I achieve client connection that is in same AWS region and VPC less than 30 milli seconds

Tags: java, apache, amazon-web-services, https

What are all the ways to connect a client with in 30 milli seconds to send a post request . Both producer and consumer are in same AWS region and same VPC.

I wrote a sample client but it is taking more than 30 milli seconds.The client in the same vpc request the server with the private ip.

Client is running on 2 instances.

Server logic is taking less than 10ms. This will just connect the redis and sends the response.

Please advice what are the possible ways to achieve a connection with in 30 milli seconds if both consumer and producer are on same VPC and same AWS region.

```
      HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(
            "elb/endpoint");

    httpPost.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    String stringRequest = request.toString();

    StringEntity stringEntity = new StringEntity(stringRequest, Charsets.UTF_8);
    httpPost.setConfig(getRequestConfig());
    httpPost.setEntity(stringEntity);

    logger.info("Client sent time");
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

 try (CloseableHttpClient client = getCloseableClient();
            CloseableHttpResponse httpResponse = client.execute(httpPost)) {

        logger.info("Client received time");
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();

        responses = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity, "UTF-8");


        long duration = endTime - start;
        report.duration = duration;
        report.scriptTime = entity.processTime;

    } catch (Exception ex) {

        throw new Exception(ex.getMessage());
    }
private RequestConfig getRequestConfig() {
    RequestConfig requestConfig = RequestConfig.custom().setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
            .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout).build();
    return requestConfig;
}
private CloseableHttpClient getCloseableClient() {
    CloseableHttpClient httpClient = null;
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    try {
        initSSLSocketFactory();

        Registry<ConnectionSocketFactory> r = RegistryBuilder.<ConnectionSocketFactory> create()
                .register("http", PlainConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory())
                .register("https", sslSocketFactory).build();

        HttpClientConnectionManager connMgr = pooling
                ? new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager(r)
                : new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager(r);

        HttpClientBuilder builder = HttpClients.custom();
        builder.setConnectionManager(connMgr);
        httpClient = builder.build();
        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        long getCloseableClientTime = endTime - startTime;

        logger.info("getCloseableClientTime method {}", getCloseableClientTime);



        return httpClient;
    } catch (Exception ex) {

    }
    return httpClient;
}

private SSLConnectionSocketFactory initSSLSocketFactory() {
    if (sslSocketFactory == null) {
        try {
            TrustStrategy trustStrategy = new TrustSelfSignedStrategy();
            SSLContextBuilder sslContextBuilder = SSLContexts.custom()
                    .loadTrustMaterial(trustStrategy);

            SSLContext sslContext = sslContextBuilder.build();
            sslSocketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext,
                    NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            String message = "Unable to create the SSL socket factory.";

        }
    }
    return sslSocketFactory;

}
```

Comment: Need a lot more information. Did the client in the same vpc request the server with the private ip or with the public ip? What instance size are you using? the request took more than 30ms because of your server logic or not? Did you try pinging between the 2 instances already? (please tell me the latency also because it will be latency[client -> server] + server processing time + latency [server -> client])

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply! I have edited my question with below : The client in the same vpc request the server with the private ip. Client is running on 2 instances. I am trying to PING the client EC2 instances as I am new to this figuring out the process as I need to update the security groups etc. Also , Server logic is taking less than 10ms.

Comment: I tried to ping ec2 but it is time out :

64 bytes from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=128 ttl=57 time=17.564 ms
64 bytes from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=129 ttl=57 time=17.640 ms
64 bytes from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=130 ttl=57 time=16.722 ms
64 bytes from 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: icmp_seq=131 ttl=57 time=17.011 ms
^C
--- 10.xxx.xxx.xxx: ping statistics ---
132 packets transmitted, 132 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 16.090/25.508/406.594/36.190 ms

Comment: same VPC also same subnet if different subnet is it in another availability zone?

Comment: Same VPC also same subnet. These subnets are not available in other zone.

Comment: Which region is this the latency seems higher than usual it should be no more than 5ms

Comment: This us-west-1(N.california). Also I am doing some POC on adding rest service on API gateway hope for Better result, can I have your thoughts on this please? . As mentioned it should be no  more than 5ms meaning client connection should be coded in better way ? If 5 ms then no issue in client response, because client responds in less than 10ms. Do you have any use case or code that connects in  5ms ?